# Replacing (lava lamp's) animation color palettes which are randomly generated, with two pre-defined ones?

Tags: animation, math, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

So I've been following a [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/fun-with-html-canvas-lets-make-lava-lamp-plasma-e4b0d89fe778) that details creation of vanilla js+html lava/plasma canvas animation. It uses pixelBuffer, and animates via requestAnimationFrame, and tick.

The final code is generating random colors for 2 palettes, but I want 2 pre-defined palettes, because I want only 3 major colors, and their shades to interact / blend / plasm...

So, I tried some simple editing (will include before and after below), and upon saving/updating the code - I just get white screen. I don't fully understand the code, but it is not obvious to me where the trouble is. So can someone point it out, or ask me leading questions, where you would look to figure things out?

before/original/random-color code in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-surf-jci4z?file=/index.html

I can't share mine, cause it requires pro version, but the only things I changed (see end of original code in the "colour helpers" section) is removing the randomColour function, the makeRandomPalette function, makeFiveColourGradient, and const palettes with the following:

I know it's not right, and can see some errors I didn't edit, but I'm trying to figure out if I'm thinking in the right direction. And maybe it's obvious to someone else, how some pre-defined palettes could be worked in.

```
// color helpers

    const interpolate = (c1, c2, f) => {
      return {
        r: Math.floor(c1.r + (c2.r - c1.r) * f),
        g: Math.floor(c1.g + (c2.g - c1.g) * f),
        b: Math.floor(c1.b + (c2.b - c1.b) * f)
      };
    };

    // random color was returned here before

    const palette1 = [
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 },
      { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 },
      { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 0 }
    ];

    const palette2 = [
      { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 },
      { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 },
      { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 }
    ];

    // offsets for moving height maps
    let dx1 = 0;
    let dy1 = 0;

    let dx2 = 0;
    let dy2 = 0;

    // adjust height maps offsets
    const moveHeightMaps = (t) => {
      dx1 = Math.floor(
        (((Math.cos(t * 0.0002 + 0.4 + Math.PI) + 1) / 2) * mapSize) / 2
      );
      dy1 = Math.floor((((Math.cos(t * 0.0003 - 0.1) + 1) / 2) * mapSize) / 2);
      dx2 = Math.floor((((Math.cos(t * -0.0002 + 1.2) + 1) / 2) * mapSize) / 2);
      dy2 = Math.floor(
        (((Math.cos(t * -0.0003 - 0.8 + Math.PI) + 1) / 2) * mapSize) / 2
      );
    };

    // two palettes we interpolate between
    const palettes = [palette1, palette2];

    // current palette is edstablished durting animation
    let palette = [];

    // stores whether we're interpolating colors
    // from palette 0 -> 1 (1) or 1 -> 0 (-1)
    let prevDirection = 1;

    const updatePalette = (t) => {
      const timeScale = 0.0005;
      const x = t * timeScale;

      // normalized value 0..1 used to interpolate palette colors
      const inter = (Math.cos(x) + 1) / 2;

      // did we switch direction, and should ergo pick a new palette
      // random palette to interpolate towards?

      const direction = -Math.sin(x) >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
      if (prevDirection != direction) {
        prevDirection = direction;
        if (direction == -1) {
          palettes[0] = makeRandomPalette();
        } else {
          palettes[1] = makeRandomPalette();
        }
      }

      // create interpolated palette for current frame
      for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        palette[i] = interpolate(palettes[0][i], palettes[1][i], inter);
      }
    };

    const updateImageData = () => {
      for (let u = 0; u < imgSize; u++) {
        for (let v = 0; v < imgSize; v++) {
          // indexes into height maps for pixel
          const i = (u + dy1) * mapSize + (v + dx1);
          const k = (u + dy2) * mapSize + (v + dx2);

          // index for pixel in image data
          // remember it's 4 bytes per pixel
          const j = u * imgSize * 4 + v * 4;

          // height value of 0..255
          let h = heightMap1[i] + heightMap2[k];
          // get color value from current palette
          let c = palette[h];

          // h = heightMap2[i];
          // c = { r: h, g: h, b: h };

          // set pixel data
          image.data[j] = c.r;
          image.data[j + 1] = c.g;
          image.data[j + 2] = c.b;
        }
      }
    };

    // helper to create a linear gradient palette
    const linearGradient = (c1, c2) => {
      const g = [];

      // interpolate between the colors
      // in the gradient

      for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        const f = i / 255;
        g[i] = interpolate(c1, c2, f);
      }

      return g;
    };

    const tick = (time) => {
      moveHeightMaps(time);
      updatePalette(time);
      updateImageData();

      c.putImageData(image, 0, 0);

      requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    };
```

Thanks for anyone who points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on, we need to examine what the **original** code is doing.

```
const palettes = [makeRandomPalette(), makeRandomPalette()];
```

This bit of code is calling the `makeRandomPalette()` function two times, to push whatever it returns into the `palettes` array.

So if we look up the `makeRandomPalette()` function definition:

```
 const makeRandomPalette = () => {
      const c1 = randomColor();
      const c2 = randomColor();
      const c3 = randomColor();
      const c4 = randomColor();
      const c5 = randomColor();

      return makeFiveColorGradient(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5);
    };
```

we can see it populates 5 constants `c1`-`c5` with rgb color objects returned by the `randomColor()` function **and** sends those constants to another function called `makeFiveColorGradient()` which takes the 5 colors and turns it into an array of 256 color values - which is the final color palette. This array is what actually gets pushed into the `palettes` array and is completely missing in your edits.

What you have is a bit like this:

```
const palette1 = [
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 },
      { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 },
      { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 0 }
    ];

    const palette2 = [
      { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 },
      { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 },
      { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 }
    ];

const palettes = [palette1, palette2];
```

So you're simply pushing the arrays of 5 color values into the `palettes` array without handling those by the `makeFiveColorGradient()` function.

Here's your fixed code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

// size of canvas
const imgSize = 512;

canvas.width = imgSize;
canvas.height = imgSize;

// init image data with black pixels
const image = c.createImageData(imgSize, imgSize);
for (let i = 0; i < image.data.length; i += 4) {
  image.data[i] = 0; // R
  image.data[i + 1] = 0; // G
  image.data[i + 2] = 0; // B
  image.data[i + 3] = 255; // A
}

// size of our height maps
const mapSize = 1024;

// returns the distance of point x,y from the origin 0,0
const distance = (x, y) => Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

// init height map 1
const heightMap1 = [];
for (let u = 0; u < mapSize; u++) {
  for (let v = 0; v < mapSize; v++) {
    // index of coordinate in height map array
    const i = u * mapSize + v;

    // u,v are coordinates with origin at upper left corner
    // cx and cy are coordinates with origin at the
    // center of the map
    const cx = u - mapSize / 2;
    const cy = v - mapSize / 2;

    // distance from middle of map
    const d = distance(cx, cy);

    // stretching so we get the desired ripple density on our map
    const stretch = (3 * Math.PI) / (mapSize / 2);

    // wavy height value between -1 and 1
    const ripple = Math.sin(d * stretch);

    // wavy height value normalized to 0..1
    const normalized = (ripple + 1) / 2;

    // height map value 0..128, integer
    heightMap1[i] = Math.floor(normalized * 128);
  }
}

const heightMap2 = [];
for (let u = 0; u < mapSize; u++) {
  for (let v = 0; v < mapSize; v++) {
    const i = u * mapSize + v;
    const cx = u - mapSize / 2;
    const cy = v - mapSize / 2;

    // skewed distance as input to chaos field calculation,
    // scaled for smoothness over map distance
    const d1 = distance(0.8 * cx, 1.3 * cy) * 0.022;
    const d2 = distance(1.35 * cx, 0.45 * cy) * 0.022;

    const s = Math.sin(d1);
    const c = Math.cos(d2);
    // height value between -2 and +2
    const h = s + c;

    // height value between 0..1
    const normalized = (h + 2) / 4;
    // height value between 0..127, integer
    heightMap2[i] = Math.floor(normalized * 127);
  }
}

// color helpers

const interpolate = (c1, c2, f) => {
  return {
    r: Math.floor(c1.r + (c2.r - c1.r) * f),
    g: Math.floor(c1.g + (c2.g - c1.g) * f),
    b: Math.floor(c1.b + (c2.b - c1.b) * f)
  };
};

// returns a random color
const randomColor = () => {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  return {
    r,
    g,
    b
  };
};

// returns a random color palette with 256 color entries
const makeRandomPalette = () => {
  const c1 = randomColor();
  const c2 = randomColor();
  const c3 = randomColor();
  const c4 = randomColor();
  const c5 = randomColor();

  return makeFiveColorGradient(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5);
};

const generatePalette = (palette) => {
  return makeFiveColorGradient(...palette);
};

const makeFiveColorGradient = (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) => {
  const g = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    const f = i / 64;
    g[i] = interpolate(c1, c2, f);
  }

  for (let i = 64; i < 128; i++) {
    const f = (i - 64) / 64;
    g[i] = interpolate(c2, c3, f);
  }

  for (let i = 128; i < 192; i++) {
    const f = (i - 128) / 64;
    g[i] = interpolate(c3, c4, f);
  }

  for (let i = 192; i < 256; i++) {
    const f = (i - 192) / 64;
    g[i] = interpolate(c4, c5, f);
  }

  return g;
};

// offsets for moving height maps
let dx1 = 0;
let dy1 = 0;

let dx2 = 0;
let dy2 = 0;

// adjust height maps offsets
const moveHeightMaps = t => {
  dx1 = Math.floor(
    (((Math.cos(t * 0.0002 + 0.4 + Math.PI) + 1) / 2) * mapSize) / 2
  );
  dy1 = Math.floor((((Math.cos(t * 0.0003 - 0.1) + 1) / 2) * mapSize) / 2);
  dx2 = Math.floor((((Math.cos(t * -0.0002 + 1.2) + 1) / 2) * mapSize) / 2);
  dy2 = Math.floor(
    (((Math.cos(t * -0.0003 - 0.8 + Math.PI) + 1) / 2) * mapSize) / 2
  );
};

const palette1 = [{
    r: 255,
    g: 255,
    b: 255
  },
  {
    r: 255,
    g: 0,
    b: 0
  },
  {
    r: 0,
    g: 255,
    b: 0
  },
  {
    r: 0,
    g: 0,
    b: 255
  },
  {
    r: 255,
    g: 255,
    b: 0
  }
];

const palette2 = [{
    r: 0,
    g: 0,
    b: 0
  },
  {
    r: 255,
    g: 255,
    b: 255
  },
  {
    r: 255,
    g: 0,
    b: 0
  },
  {
    r: 0,
    g: 255,
    b: 0
  },
  {
    r: 0,
    g: 0,
    b: 255
  }
];

// two palettes we interpolate between
const palettes = [generatePalette(palette1), generatePalette(palette2)];

// current palette is edstablished durting animation
let palette = [];

// stores whether we're interpolating colors
// from palette 0 -> 1 (1) or 1 -> 0 (-1)
let prevDirection = 1;

const updatePalette = t => {
  const timeScale = 0.0005;
  const x = t * timeScale;

  // normalized value 0..1 used to interpolate palette colors
  const inter = (Math.cos(x) + 1) / 2;

  // did we switch direction, and should ergo pick a new palette
  // random palette to interpolate towards?

  const direction = -Math.sin(x) >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
  if (prevDirection != direction) {
    prevDirection = direction;
    if (direction == -1) {
      palettes[0] = generatePalette(palette1);
    } else {
      palettes[1] = generatePalette(palette2);
    }
  }

  // create interpolated palette for current frame
  for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    palette[i] = interpolate(palettes[0][i], palettes[1][i], inter);
  }
};

const updateImageData = () => {
  for (let u = 0; u < imgSize; u++) {
    for (let v = 0; v < imgSize; v++) {
      // indexes into height maps for pixel
      const i = (u + dy1) * mapSize + (v + dx1);
      const k = (u + dy2) * mapSize + (v + dx2);

      // index for pixel in image data
      // remember it's 4 bytes per pixel
      const j = u * imgSize * 4 + v * 4;

      // height value of 0..255
      let h = heightMap1[i] + heightMap2[k];
      // get color value from current palette
      let c = palette[h];

      // h = heightMap2[i];
      // c = { r: h, g: h, b: h };

      // set pixel data
      image.data[j] = c.r;
      image.data[j + 1] = c.g;
      image.data[j + 2] = c.b;
    }
  }
};

// helper to create a linear gradient palette
const linearGradient = (c1, c2) => {
  const g = [];

  // interpolate between the colors
  // in the gradient

  for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    const f = i / 255;
    g[i] = interpolate(c1, c2, f);
  }

  return g;
};

const tick = time => {
  moveHeightMaps(time);
  updatePalette(time);
  updateImageData();

  c.putImageData(image, 0, 0);

  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0;margin: 0;"></canvas>
```